# Usage of message queue fork + execlp + ftok

Tags: c

The main purpose here is to create a message queue by executing thise command : ./create_msg_queue fileForQueue

We want to create the file fileForQueue if it doesn't exist.

Regarding my code, if the file doesn't exist, I get this error

> ftok: No such file or directory

So how can I have this file create BEFORE ftok() is called with the file name ?

Provided code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// IPC and KEYS -------------
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
//---------------------------

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

// message structure
typedef struct {

    // id message
    long type;

    // Size : 12 bytes
    double mesure;
    pid_t pidClient;

} message_t;

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {

    key_t key;
    message_t message;
    int file;
    int pid;

    // Check arg number
    if (argc != 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Syntaxe : %s fichier_clé\n",argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create the empty file given in parameter
    if ((pid = vfork()) == -1)
    {  
         perror("fork");
         exit(1);
    }

    if (pid)
    {   
         // code replacement to create the FILE
         execlp("touch", "touch", argv[1], NULL);
         perror("execlp"); 
         exit(1);
    }else
    {
        // Trying to wait for the forked() process to finish its file creation
        wait (NULL);

            // I GET ERROR HERE IF THE FILE DON'T EXIST BEFORE I LAUNCH THE PROGRAM
        // Create key with the file given in parameter and then created
        if ((key = ftok(argv[1], 0)) == -1) {

            // errNo value
            perror("ftok");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Create message queue
        if ((file = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
           perror("msgget");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Registering message content
        message.type = 1;
        message.mesure = -1;
        message.pidClient = getpid();

            // Sending message
        if (msgsnd(file, (void *) & message, 12, 0) <0) {
           perror("msgsnd");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help. I struggle :)

Comment: Well i get and error, i would like to not have any error I'll edit to be more precise.

Comment: Is it more clear ? ^^

Comment: The right answer is to use POSIX IPC (`mq_open()` etc.) if at all possible instead of the baroque SysV IPC APIs.

Comment: :) thanks for info . It's a school work . I am new to C :)

Comment: I actually assumed as much, schools usually take several decades before they teach modern techniques of doing anything.

Comment: Anyway, what you need to do here is just open the `fileForQueue` for writing and immediately close it to create an empty file - no need to mess with calling `touch`.

Comment: Yes but, how to. The fileForQueue is provided on run, and if this file doesnt exist we have to create it.

Comment: That's what I said. `fopen()` it for writing, then `fclose()` it. Check the man page for `fopen()` to see which mode to use (should be `"a"`) so you don't erase its contents if it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
key_t ftok(const char *path, int id);


ftok(argv[1], 0))
```

> Only the low-order 8-bits of id are significant. The behavior of
>   ftok() is unspecified if these bits are 0.

Also note that you have to

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

at the very begin

Comment: Also please , why do I have to specify this _XOPEN_SOURCE ? Just working for school exercice. (Really stucked on this)

Comment: Ok, type `gdb program_name` then `run file_name`

Comment: `_XOPEN_SOURCE` tells your compiler to include definitions for some extra functions that are defined in the POSIX standards.

Comment: I dont understand "type gdb program_name then run file_name" (Sorry i am kinda new to Linux / and C programming)

Comment: Debug your program, in a terminal type `gdb program_name` where program_name is the name of your executable, when gdb returns >, type `run file_name` where filename is the argument you pass to the program (argv[1])

Comment: Very great information David RF. Thanks a lot. I have to install few stuff in order to be able to debug. this is awsome :p

Comment: This is a massive wild goose chase, the `fork`/`exec` to call `touch` is pointless and a much easier solution is to get rid of it instead of attempting to debug it. (Assuming the OP's assignment doesn't explicitly state that's how the file should be created but I doubt that.)

Comment: You are welcome, remember to compile with `-g` for debug e.g: `gcc -g myfile.c -o myfile` [more info](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-g.htm)

Comment: Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.i686
I have this glibc installed yet

Comment: Are you on Fedora / Red Hat / CentOs ?

Comment: I use Fedora, trying to fix this with /etc/yum.repos.d/ repos

Comment: I get this error Error importing repomd.xml from fedora-debuginfo: Unable to open /var/cache/yum/i386/16/fedora-debuginfo/repomd.xml

Comment: `rpm yum-utils` `debuginfo-install glibc`

Comment: Already did these commands I found info here http://digitizor.com/2009/06/17/how-to-fix-the-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-error-in-fedora-11/

Comment: I remember to have the same problem some time ago under Fedora, but I don't remember how to fix, sorry now I use Debian :(

Comment: Riiiight i can debug now :)
There :
Detaching after fork from child process 9046.
ftok: No such file or directory
process 9043 is executing new program: /bin/touch

It seems that ftok comes BEFORE touch : I thought of that . but i tried to make the main thread wait for the end of the son with wait(NULL) .. I dont know why touch comes after ftok()

Comment: Its OK , i found a way here : http://digitizor.com/2009/06/17/how-to-fix-the-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-error-in-fedora-11/

Comment: Aha, you are on the right way jajaja [ENOENT] The directory or a component of the path name specified does not exist. Follow the advice of millimoose (use fopen and fclose to create the file)